# Strange light green background color for selected option in selectmenu jquery mobile and cordova 4 cli

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, mobile, select-menu

Please see the screenshot on the link below.

i'm using selectmenu from jquery mobile and building the app for android in cordova CLI , the select menu selected option has a strange green color background, i tried the following css without any result:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important; 
}

select option {
    background-color:#ffffff !important;    
}

select option:checked {
    background-color:#ffffff !important;    
}
```

I was not facing this problem when i was using the "phonegap build" with phonegap 3.6 version.

I don't think the problem is in css, it might be from cordova build?

I have faced this problem also for data-native-menu= "false"

Screenshot link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2nIP5MeGtfPWmtMT2JabkN2Tm8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having a similar problem, but found a solution in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170978

It looks like the green styling of the select menu is controlled by the default theme specified in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Changing it to

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"`

fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you very much!, exactly what i was looking for! .. that solved my problem, i was struggling with it and didn't find an answer, i thought it's from JQuery's CSS, Great done :) appreciate your help